# ¿Cómo guardo una lista de Python en excel con xlwt?

Tags: python, excel

Tengo una lista llamada "distancias":

```
print(distancias)
[757, 41, 75, 343, 26, 247, 32, 61, 68, 49, 97, 22, 278]
```

Necesito pasar estos datos a un excel con xlwt. He hecho

```
fichero_distancias = xlwt.Workbook()
datos = fichero_distancias.add_sheet("datos")
datos.write(0,0, distancias)
fichero_distancias.save("ruta")
```

Estas instrucciones crean el fichero y la hoja, pero no añaden los datos de la lista. Es decir, el fichero creado no contiene ningún dato. ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí me ha funcionado insertando los elementos de la lista uno a uno en la hoja de cálculo:

```
import xlwt

distancias=[757, 41, 75, 343, 26, 247, 32, 61, 68, 49, 97, 22, 278]
print(distancias)

fichero_distancias = xlwt.Workbook()
datos = fichero_distancias.add_sheet("datos")

for i in range(len(distancias)):
    datos.write(i, 0, distancias[i])

fichero_distancias.save("ruta.xls")
```